# Как обвести в div блок каждую сгенерированную цифру в комбинации?

Tags: javascript, html

Код комбинирует комбинации цифр от 1 до 25 по 5 цифр на комбинацию. Как обвести каждую цифру в див блок?

```js
function generate() {
  const numbers = (new Array(25)).fill(1).map((a, i) => a + i);
  let resultSet = new Map();
  while (resultSet.size < 1000) {
    let nums = shuffle(numbers).slice(0, 5);
    let key = (nums.sort() + '');
    resultSet.set(key, nums);
  }

  resultSet.forEach(val => document.write(val.join('-') + '<br>', 
));
}

function shuffle(arr) {
  return arr.map(el => {
    return {
      item: el,
      sort: Math.random()
    }
  }).sort((a, b) => a.sort - b.sort).map(el => el.item);
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="Нажать" onclick="generate()"/>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
function  generate() {
  const numbers = (new Array(25)).fill(1).map((a, i) => a + i);
  let resultSet = new Map();
  while (resultSet.size < 1000) {
    let nums = shuffle(numbers).slice(0, 5);
    let key = (nums.sort() + '');
    resultSet.set(key, nums);
  }
  resultSet.forEach(val => {
    const main = createDivWithContent(val.join('-'), "one");
    const additional = createDivWithContent(randInt(), "two");
    main.append(additional);
    document.body.append(main);
  })
}

function shuffle(arr) {
  return arr.map(el => {
    return {
      item: el,
      sort: Math.random()
    }
  }).sort((a, b) => a.sort - b.sort).map(el => el.item);
}

function randInt(min = 1, max = 4) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}

function createDivWithContent(content, className) {
  const divEl = document.createElement("DIV");
  divEl.className = className || "";
  divEl.append(content);
  return divEl;
}
```

```css
.one {
  color: grey;
}
.two {
  color: blue;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="Нажать" onclick="generate()"/>
```

Comment: Так у меня не получится присвоить стиль диву.

Comment: Вы хотите стили для каждого дива по отдельности или же использование класса одного на всех подойдет?

Comment: можно одного для всех, кроме вот этой randInt(min = 1, max = 4)   для нее стиль отдельный нужен

Comment: Обновил, теперь можно передавать название класса

Comment: Все отлично, только теперь .two переходит на строчку ниже, а должно все на одной строчке. Получается .one и .two дополнительно не обернуты в общий див

Comment: Обернул, проверьте

Comment: Спасибо большое!